# NoSuchMethodError: AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;Ljava/lang/Object;)V

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm writing a project using:
    Eclipse Luna, JDK 1.7_09, Hibernate 4.3.7.Final, Spring 4.1.2.RELEASE

When deploying to a local Tomcat 7, the webapp starts to initialize, but I get the following:

```
Nov 30, 2014 4:56:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\javapkgs\Java64\jdk1.7.0_09\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;c:/javapkgs/java64/jdk1.7.0_09/bin/../jre/bin/server;c:/javapkgs/java64/jdk1.7.0_09/bin/../jre/bin;c:/javapkgs/java64/jdk1.7.0_09/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;c:\javapkgs\java64\jdk1.7.0_09\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\Fusion Media Explorer\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\10.0\DLLShared\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\jZip;C:\Program Files (x86)\Pinnacle\Shared Files\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Pinnacle\Shared Files\Filter\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Windows\system32;;.
Nov 30, 2014 4:56:31 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:server' did not find a matching property.
Nov 30, 2014 4:56:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 30, 2014 4:56:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 30, 2014 4:56:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 740 ms
Nov 30, 2014 4:56:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Nov 30, 2014 4:56:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.39
Nov 30, 2014 4:56:32 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(D:\projects\MyMenuMemory\svnWorkspace2\ws\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\server\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Nov 30, 2014 4:56:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Nov 30, 2014 4:56:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Nov 30, 2014 4:56:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [contexts/context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)
at o    rg.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
at o    rg.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
at o    rg.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
at o    rg.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at o    rg.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
at o    rg.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at j    ava.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at j    ava.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.parseInternal(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:54)
at o    rg.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:60)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1427)
at o    rg.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:144)
at o    rg.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
...     23 more

Nov 30, 2014 4:56:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Nov 30, 2014 4:56:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/server] startup failed due to previous errors
Nov 30, 2014 4:56:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Nov 30, 2014 4:56:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:170)
at o    rg.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:884)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:836)
at o    rg.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:579)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4927)
at o    rg.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5573)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
at o    rg.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at j    ava.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at j    ava.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Nov 30, 2014 4:56:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 30, 2014 4:56:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 30, 2014 4:56:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4776 ms
```

I ran mvn dependency:tree and only have one version of spring-aop (4.1.2.RELEASE).

I have tried reading many posts about this, but most reference Spring/Hibernate 3 not 4.  Am I just missing something?  This is my first from-scratch Spring/Hibernate project.

Please help, I'm at my whit's end!

David

Answer (score 0):

In Spring 4.0.0 many deprecated methods were removed.

org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(ParserContext parserContext, java.lang.Object source)

was one that was removed.

See

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#_removed_deprecated_packages_and_methods

You should check to see what other Spring jars are being loaded. I notice in the trace above

Nov 30, 2014 4:56:32 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(D:\projects\MyMenuMemory\svnWorkspace2\ws.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\server\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class

This jar should not be part of the web application. It is provided by the container (Tomcat).

Comment: I took out the servlet-api jar even though it wasn't being loaded.  No change, but thanks for the link... I'll check it out.

Comment: Well, I tried to take it out, but it turns out I need it for referencing HttpServletRequest.  I did switch it to 'provided' scope.

Comment: It seems as if the issue is with the spring-tx library maybe?  Looking at the caused by stack:  Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
 at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.parseInternal(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:54) I would associate that to the <tx:annotation-driven/> line in my context.xml.  If I comment that out, the error goes away, but do my Annotated transaction go away?

Comment: Are you able to include the output from mvn dependency:tree ?

Answer (score 0):

This problem usually appears when you have more than one Spring JAR with different versions in your classpath. Check for this.

In my case, I had `spring-dao` and `spring-tx` as well. `spring-dao` was an old one and I removed it. After that, it resolved my error.